# I want to read a file and store some variables with AWK

Tags: regex, shell, awk, readfile, text-processing

I have a file with the following content. it is the result of a query in an equipment, so it is expected that some input are not found in the database. The following examples are the result of successful and unsuccessful queries. I mean that the second example does not have all the information that I want to capture into the variables, so i want to ignore this result and set the variables with null/empty values.

```
<INTLPO:ISV=PORTAB NTL="6130290095" VEM=NAO;
VECTURA - SS            BSA002             2020-09-12            09-32
INTLPO:ISV=PORTAB NTL="6130290095" VEM=NAO;
INTERROGACAO DE NUMERO TELEFONICO PARA PORTABILIDADE NUMERICA                   

  TIPO DE ENCAMINHAMENTO POR ASSINANTE
  NTL = 6130290095           OPC = S_INF    RNP = 551      CSP = 25
  EIP = S_INF
  CDO = 00961
  CNL = 61000                NUF = S_INF                   TPB = PREST
  CPT = NAO                  CRE = 125      NUE = S_INF
  DAT = 2014-04-16           HOR = 10:30:20.798609
  TBR = 25
  RST              MAN      RST              MAN      RST              MAN
  2%               934      3%               934      4%               934
  5%               934      6%               934      7%               934
  8%               934      9%               934      9090%            934
  0??%             934      90??%            934      0?0%             934


  TOTAL DE NUMEROS ASSOCIADOS AO SERVICO: 1
```

```
<INTLPO:ISV=PORTAB NTL="6160150178" VEM=NAO;
VECTURA - SS            BSA002             2020-09-12            09-32
INTLPO:ISV=PORTAB NTL="6160150178" VEM=NAO;
INTERROGACAO DE NUMERO TELEFONICO PARA PORTABILIDADE NUMERICA                   

  ME:  NENHUM NUMERO CADASTRADO ATENDE AS ESPECIFICACOES
```

I have the following code which is partially ok. The result is a little mess up yet (the lines are repeating and even with wrong values).

```
awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN { OFS="," }
            /^VECTURA/ { equipment = $4; data = $5 }
            /^INTLPO/ { numero = $2}
            /^\s*NTL/ { ntl = $3 ; opc = $6; rnp = $9; csp = $12}
            /^\s*EIP/ { eip = $3}
            /^\s*CDO/ { cdo = $3}
            /^\s*CNL/ { cnl = $3; nuf = $6; tpb = $9}
            /^\s*CPT/ { cpt = $3; cre = $6; nue = $9}
            /^\s*DAT/ { dat = $3; hor = $6}
            /^\s*TBR/ { tbr = $3}
            /^\s*RST/ { man = $2; next}
            { print data, equipment, numero, ntl, opc, rnp, csp, eip, cdo, cnl, nuf, tpb, cpt, cre, nue, dat, hor, tbr, man}' input.tx >> output.txt
```

result

```
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150536,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150536,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,,,,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,,,,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,,,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150178,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150178,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150178,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150178,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150178,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150178,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
2020-09-12,BSA002,6160150178,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,MAN
```

note that the record 6130290095 (variable NTL) is wrongly associated with the "number" record (last lines of the example above).

How could I overcome that? I have tried some AWK conditional statement but wasn't successful either.
As a output i would like just one line by record, as some lines of the output example can exemplify.
thanks a lot.

Comment: When you want to print the result only once, use `END { print ...}`.

Comment: Please include the expected output for your sample input file. Is it a file and how it looks like? (Or a bash array?)

Comment: I don't want to print only once. I want to print only once **per record**. Eg: I have a list of 50 queries and some of them have all the information I need and some don't. The output is a list of 50 'number' records, for those who has all the information I would like to print them separated by coma (like the last ones in the example provided before), and those who don't, be printed like "6130300000,BSA2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,".....

Comment: the input is a file as shown in the script (input.txt >> output.txt).. Thanks again.

Comment: What do you what to extract from RST MAN lines?

Comment: The code is wrong. I want the MAN number (934), I changed the code to /^\s*2%/.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please update the code and expected output in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only want to change the value of `numero` when  it is not set, add a test like `numero ||`.
After reading your comment I changed my solution. As I understand now, you don't want one record with the results fo all blocks combined, but you want one resulting line for each block processed. Each new block starts with `<INTLPO`.
This solution will make all values empty at the start of a new block (not needed for the first block but it won't harm).
The results of a block are shown, when a new block is found and when we are at the end of the file.

```
awk 'function newrecord() {
        recordnumber++;
        data=equipment=numero=ntl=opc=rnp=csp=eip=cdo="";
        cnl=nuf=tpb=cpt=cre=nue=dat=hor=tbr=man="";
     }
     function printrecord() {
         print data, equipment, numero, ntl, opc, rnp, csp, eip,
               cdo, cnl, nuf, tpb, cpt, cre, nue, dat, hor, tbr, man;
     }

     BEGIN { OFS="," }
            /^<INTLPO/ { if (recordnumber) printrecord(); newrecord(); }
            /^VECTURA/ { equipment = $4; data = $5 }
            /^INTLPO/ { numero = $2}
            /^\s*NTL/ { ntl = $3 ; opc = $6; rnp = $9; csp = $12}
            /^\s*EIP/ { eip = $3}
            /^\s*CDO/ { cdo = $3}
            /^\s*CNL/ { cnl = $3; nuf = $6; tpb = $9}
            /^\s*CPT/ { cpt = $3; cre = $6; nue = $9}
            /^\s*DAT/ { dat = $3; hor = $6}
            /^\s*TBR/ { tbr = $3}
            /^\s*RST/ { man = $2; next}
            END { printrecord(); }
      ' input.tx
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the answer. I've tried this and did not work. I have a file with hundreads of results like the examples in the question. Part of them doesn't have the results info (because those records doesn't exist in the equipment's database). But I want to write an output with all the records. One line per input record with all the available info. When the block of info doesn't have all the infos I would like to print them with the minimum info they have (eg 2020-09-12,BSA2,6130300020,,,,,,,,,,,,)...

Comment: thank you very much, you got that. your solution is elegant yet simple, it worked precisely, no words to thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach any problem where you have `tag = value` pairs is to first populate an array of that mapping (`tag2val[]` below) and then you can access whatever values you like by their tags (names) in whatever order you like.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    numTags = split("\
                EQUIPMENT \
                DATE \
                NUMERO \
                NTL \
                OPC \
                RNP \
                CSP \
                EIP \
                CDO \
                CNL \
                NUF \
                TPB \
                CPT \
                CRE \
                NUE \
                DAT \
                HOR \
                TBR \
                MAN \
                ",tags)
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
/^</ && (NR > 1) {
    prt()
    delete tag2val
}
$1 == "VECTURA" {
    tag2val["EQUIPMENT"] = $4
    tag2val["DATE"] = $5
}
/^INTLPO/ {
    gsub(/^[^"]+"|"$/,"",$2)
    tag2val["NUMERO"] = $2
}
/^([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+ = [^[:space:]]+)+$/ {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=3) {
        tag2val[$i] = $(i+2)
    }
}
nextLineTag != "" {
    tag2val[nextLineTag] = $2
    nextLineTag = ""
}
/^[[:space:]]*RST[[:space:]]+MAN/ {
    nextLineTag = "MAN"
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   tagNr, tag, val) {
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
EQUIPMENT,DATE,NUMERO,NTL,OPC,RNP,CSP,EIP,CDO,CNL,NUF,TPB,CPT,CRE,NUE,DAT,HOR,TBR,MAN
BSA002,2020-09-12,6130290095,6130290095,S_INF,551,25,S_INF,00961,61000,S_INF,PREST,NAO,125,S_INF,2014-04-16,10:30:20.798609,25,934
BSA002,2020-09-12,6160150178,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```